# IndexError: list assignment index out of range con listas e input().split()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando hacer un programa en el que el usuario tenga que ingresar un carácter para luego asignarle el valor, y quiero que el carácter y el valor estén en la misma línea separados por un espacio, por lo que estoy usando input().split() para separarlo en 2 listas distintas, funciona perfectamente si solamente le asigno el valor a un carácter, pero cuando intento asignarle el valor a dos o más caracteres me sale el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 5, in <module>
    car[x], val[x] = input().split()
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

El fragmento de mi código que está causando el problema es el siguiente:

```
K = input()
car = [K]
val = [K]
for x in range(int(K)):
    car[x], val[x] = input().split()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que inicializas mal las listas, `car = [K]` crea una lista en la que los elementos son los caracteres de la cadena `K`, es decir:

```
>>> ["5"]
['5']

>>> ["12"]
['1', '2']
```

Esto hace que si `k` es `"5"`, por ejemplo, tus listas solo tienen un elemento, por lo que `car[0]` es válido, pero `car[1]` ya no es válido.

Debes hacer algo así en su lugar:

```
k = int(input())
car = [None] * k
val = [None] * k
for x in range(k):
    car[x], val[x] = input().split()
```

> ```
> 3
> a 4
> b 6
> c 13
>
> >>> car
> ['a', 'b', 'c']
> >>> val
> ['4', '6', '13']
> ```

`[None] * k` crea una lista de `k` elementos todos `None`:

> ```
> >>> [None] * 5
> [None, None, None, None, None]
> ```

---

> **Nota:** cuidado al inicializar una lista de esta forma cuando se trate de elementos mutables ya que todos los elementos son referencias
>   al mismo objeto:
>
> ```
> >>> l = [[]] * 5
> >>> l[0].append(2) 
> >>> l
> [[2], [2], [2], [2], [2]]
> ```
>
> en su lugar usar un `for:`
>
> ```
> >>> l = [[] for _ in range(5)]
> ```

---

Aparentemente un diccionario es la estructura más apropiada para almacenar la información que quieres, siempre que los caracteres sean únicos:

```
k = int(input())
chars_count = dict((input().split() for _ in range(k)))
```

> ```
> 3
> a 4
> b 6
> c 13
>
> >>> chars_count
> {'a': '4', 'b': '6', 'c': '13'}
>
> >>> chars_count["c"]
> "13"
> >>> chars_counts["a"]
> "4"
> ```

Otra forma, haciendo  un casting a entero del valor previamente:

```
k = int(input())
chars_count = {}

for _ in range(k):
    char, value = input().split()
    chars_count[char] = int(value)

# Lo mismo usando diccionarios por compresión
# chars_count = {c: int(v)  for c, v in (input().split() for _ in range(k))}
```

> ```
> 3
> a 4
> b 6
> c 13
>
> >>> chars_count
> {'a': 4, 'b': 6, 'c': 13}
> ```